# NSFetchedResultsController: How to set fallback value incase text set for `sectionNameKeyPath` doesn't exist

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**SCENARIO**

I am using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display information to my user in a `UITableView`. This information is highly dynamic with objects being added and removed often. When I am setting the `NSFetchedResultsController` I would like to section the information based on certain factors that are available **at the time** by setting the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

The object I am using is a `WorkOrder`. A `WorkOrder` will have a `Procedure` **AND** `Document` associated with it. I would like to use `documentTitle` property of the `Procedure`, preferably, to set as my section title, but sometimes a `Procedure` doesn't exist on a `WorkOrder`, sometimes there is only a `Document`. In this case, I'd like to set the section title as the `documentTitle` of the `Document` instead.

I know I can set one value as `sectionNameKeyPath` by doing the following:

```
self.frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
                         fetchRequest: request, 
                 managedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext, 
                   sectionNameKeyPath: "procedure.documentTitle", cacheName: nil)
```

**QUESTION**

How can I set `sectionNameKeyPath` to `"document.documentTitle"` **IF** `"procedure.documentTitle"` doesn't work out?

Comment: Maybe you should declare a getter method on WorkOrder that returns procedure.documentTitle or document.documentTitle if the former does not exist and use that as your sectionNameKeyPath?

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting this. It's obvious really. That's exactly what I did and it a beaut.